# comparing bipolar scale to unipolar scale

Tags: survey, rating

I'm trying to build some surveys and I want to ask the following questions:

> After 3 weeks, how do you feel about decision to join our company?
>
> - Very Dissatisfied
> - Moderately Dissatisfied
> - Slightly Dissatisfied
> - Neutral
> - Slightly Satisfied
> - Moderately Satisfied
> - Very Satisfied

and

> How well do you understand the company's vision?
>
> - Very well
> - Well
> - Somewhat well
> - A little
> - Not at all

Question 1 is a bipolar scale, with ratings -3 -> 3 while q2 is a unipolar 1-5. If I wanted to analyze this data and get an "average" rating, it doesn't make sense to me to just do a raw average. Should I focus on just using only bipolar or unipolar or is there a way around my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually for ordinal scales mean may not be the best statistics. If 50% of the staff said "very well" and 50% said "not at all", you can't really conclude with 'overall we know it "somewhat well."' I'd suggest first, check the distribution of the response by using bar plot (and consider reporting that plot as well) and see if a mean is a sensible statistics. You can also consider median, which is more often associated with ordinal measurements like these two.

Whether the -3 to 3 needs to be rescaled to 1 to 7 is actually not that big an issue as long as i) the coding scheme is also supplied with your statistics and ii) the direction of the score makes sense. For instance, I'd be confused by your 1-5 scale, with 5 being the most unfamiliar with the company's vision. Think about this statement: "with our annual company vision workshop we expect that the mean understanding score will decrease by 1.2 point." That's a lot of cognitive flip-flopping for the audience.

Comment: yeah i have my scales labelled so negative statements are always either negative or low on the 1-5 scale. So you think that is okay to re-scale the -3 to 3 to 1 to 5?

Comment: I'd keep them as is. If you're writing a report, then in the footnote mention "out of a 7-level scale ranging from -3 to 3", etc. I don't see anything to gain by forcing them to be the same (given your question). Also, "neutral" is a bit different than "somewhat well."